# EditText hint not visible after Transition Animation

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation

I want to animate EditText with transition animation. After completing animation, hint wont show, but when I call edittext.requestLayout or when user focuses to the edittext hint will appear. **requestLayout** soundlike a workaround what is the real solution?

```
final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
AutoTransition autoTransition = new AutoTransition();
TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
transitionSet.addTransition(autoTransition);
transitionSet.setDuration(2000);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) text.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 0;
params.height = 0;
text.setLayoutParams(params);
transitionSet.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(@NonNull Transition transition) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(@NonNull Transition transition) {
        AutoTransition autoTransition = new AutoTransition();
        TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
        transitionSet.addTransition(autoTransition);
        transitionSet.setDuration(2000);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)  text.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = -2;
        params.height = -2;
        text.setLayoutParams(params);
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) text.getParent(), transitionSet);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionCancel(@NonNull Transition transition) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionPause(@NonNull Transition transition) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionResume(@NonNull Transition transition) {

    }
});
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition((ViewGroup) text.getParent(), transitionSet);
}
```

Comment: try requestFocus()

Comment: This is the right solution to add requestFocus on edit text onTransitionEnd() method.

Comment: Is this a bug in EditText? @QandilTariq Because requestFocus makes cursor visible too. Think about this, I have a login screen with animation and I got 2 editextes here. Should I call request focus on my all edittextes?

Comment: For next focus use this series for all edit texts:
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/your_next_et_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And issue was the Android bug related with support transititon and it [resolved](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#27-1-1) in Support 27.1.1.